# Can docopt generate an argument parsing class that doesn't depend on docopt?

Tags: python, docopt

I have a small python program which will need to run on systems with core python (3.6.…) installed. I would love to use docopt to define the argument parsing (and help text), but I do not expect to be able to rely on the docopt module being available. I thought there might be an option to generate some code, possibly using argparse, with docopt, but it seems I can't find something like that. Are there side projects or ports that anyone is aware of that might do this?

Comment: So… I see that you can use the docopt.py file as a self contained utility class.
But what I mean is: could docopt output it's AST from parsing the help text, and just the methods needed to handle whats actually in the AST to a minimal version of the docopt function, custom to the current program using docopt… done during a build/generate step. I know builds aren't exactly pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

Well… it looks as though, since `docopt.py` is self-contained and 20K in size, no one thus far has felt the need to generate an argument parser from a usage specifications document to ship with a script rather than just shipping `docopt.py` with the script and reparsing the usage specifications document to generate the parser that then immediately parses the arguments at each invocation of the script or tool.